# While loop with double conditional and || logical operator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, while-loop, swift-playground

I have a While Loop with a condition that limits it to repeat only 10 times, every time a cycle is repeated a constant `D` generates a random number in a range from 0 to 24, if `D` is 0, I change a variable `dIsZero` to true and prints the cycle where `D` is 0 for the first time.

```
var S = 0  
var dIsZero = false

while S < 10 || dIsZero == false {
    S += 1
    let D = Int.random(in: 0...24)
    if dIsZero == false && D == 0 {
        dIsZero = true
        print("D = 0 in a cycle \(S)/10")
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want the While Loop can also end when `D` is 0 before the 10 cycles are completed. I already tried to put the logical operator `||` but it doesn't work and I get the following results:

- 10 cycles are exceeded until `D` is 0. For example: 84 cycles.
- If `D` is 0 before 10 cycles, the loop does not stop until that 10 cycles
  are reached.

I read about the logical operators and found the following:

> *The Swift logical operators `&&` and `||` are left-associative, meaning
>   that compound expressions with multiple logical operators evaluate the
>   leftmost subexpression first.*

**What solution do you recommend?**

Comment: Use `&&` instead

Comment: I think you're looking for `while S < 10 && dIsZero == false`, to keep looping while S is less than 10, AND `dIsZero` is not true (i.e. is false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to break loop

```
while S < 10  {
    S += 1
    let D = Int.random(in: 0...24)
     if D == 0 {
       print("D = 0 in a cycle \(S)/10")
        break
     }
}
```

Comment: This is better solution.

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: I have no query. I'm saying your solution is better :-) I upvoted it.